# Async thread - dataexchange with UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app I have to download data from a server. I put the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) request in an Async-Thread. How can I use the data (== a string) in the main UI?

The platform is Android, and the programming language is Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are actually using an `AsyncTask`, not an Async Thread (whatever that is).

From the [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) on `AsyncTask`, part "The 4 Steps":

> 1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time. The parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to the last step. This step can also use publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress. These values are published on the UI thread, in the onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field.
> 4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

You seem to be looking for the 4th method. As stated above: `onPostExecute` will be invoked in your UI Thread with the Result as the argument (The type is set as the generic parameter of the task)